# Change downloaded file name

Tags: javascript, image, angular, typescript, url

I have a function that uploads an image via a URL.
I want to change the name of the file, to download a file : 'image.jpg'.

Here's what I did:

```
public downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string): string {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = 'image.jpg';
  a.href = this.getRootUrl() + `/dicom/instances/${instanceUID}/wado/jpg`;

  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, document.defaultView, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  a.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

My image is uploaded but its name does not change, it is 'jpg.jpg'. Do you know why it's not 'image.jpg' ??

//////////////EDIT//////////////:

However, I think my error comes from `a.href`. On some examples, I saw that he was given parameters.
I tried this:

```
a.href =  "data:image/jpg;base64," + this.getRootUrl() + `/dicom/instances/${instanceUID}/wado/jpg`;
```

The file name changes well but the im not downloaded, this puts me 'network failure-error'

Comment: I tried it in pure js, it worked for me... What do you mean by the name doesn't change, when you click on the link (or trigger the event) the default proposed name is jpg.jpg`? What browser are you using?

Comment: @m.nachury
Yes when I click on the button that calls my function 'downloadImageJpeg', it automatically downloads me a file where the name is 'jpg.jpg' and not 'image.jpg'. I use Google Chrome.

Comment: Could you try this under a different browser, chrome some time ignore the download attribute if he thinks the data source is `cross-origin` which might be caused by angular. Try this under a different browser to see if it's that.

Comment: Also check on your dev tab : the request emitted by your browser when clicking the button. Look if there is a `content-Disposition` in the response http headers or any other content headers in the response or the request. I think that would override the download attribute

Comment: @m.nachury
when I use Firefox, it does not download anything to me... 
And no, under the Chrome browser there is no content-Disposition

Comment: @m.nachury
Do you have an idea to fix it ?

Comment: I'll give a last try, but that's about my limit on angular ^^. Try adding a.target="_self"; and/or just calling it using a.click (); If that doesn't work I'll recommend you go with a more "browser friendly" way, like having your a tag directly writen in your html, (hidden if you really want a button), and when working with angular use ng-href instead of href, to be sure that angular had the time to replace your ${instanceUID}.

Comment: If that still dosen't work try looking for "how to serve (download) file using angular?", good luck!

Comment: No it does not work either ...
Can you just check my post please, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function works fine:

```
export function download(url: string, filename: string) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  if (a.click) {
    // Use a.click() if available. Otherwise, Chrome might show
    // "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate a navigation change
    //  for frame with URL" and not open the PDF at all.
    // Supported by (not mentioned = untested):
    // - Firefox 6 - 19 (4- does not support a.click, 5 ignores a.click)
    // - Chrome 19 - 26 (18- does not support a.click)
    // - Opera 9 - 12.15
    // - Internet Explorer 6 - 10
    // - Safari 6 (5.1- does not support a.click)
    a.href = url;
    a.target = '_parent';
    // Use a.download if available. This increases the likelihood that
    // the file is downloaded instead of opened by another PDF plugin.
    if ('download' in a) {
      a.download = filename;
    }
    // <a> must be in the document for IE and recent Firefox versions.
    // (otherwise .click() is ignored)
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.parentNode!.removeChild(a);
  } else {
    if (window.top === window &&
      url.split('#')[0] === window.location.href.split('#')[0]) {
      // If _parent == self, then opening an identical URL with different
      // location hash will only cause a navigation, not a download.
      var padCharacter = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
      url = url.replace(/#|$/, padCharacter + '$&');
    }
    window.open(url, '_parent');
  }
}
```

## Source

From PDF viewer : https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/94089960c04d7f59eb637d6dc63944115bbc539d/web/download_manager.js#L29-L63

Comment: I can't understand ..
It does not work either .. I have always a file downloaded : 'jpg.jpg'